# FB comments are ignoring Meta tags

Tags: php, facebook

I have a website written in PHP which on which I got a facebook comments box and a FB like box. When a person clicks the like box a "message" is published in the users timeline (often) and there are details published along with it found in the meta tags. But when a user comments only the link to the website is published along with the comment and not the image for example. How can I fix this?

These are my meta tags:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Example.com" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://Example.com/" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://example.com/images/logo.png" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Example.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="We create magic for you on the Internet."/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Facebooks Debug Tool to check your URL.

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

It's possible that your Site is already in their cache.
By using this tool, the cache will be cleared.